# Creating a String expression when given an expression tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, expression-trees

I am having trouble creating a String expression when given an expression tree. If my expression tree looks like this (in the output console):

```
(*(+(5)(-(2)(3)))(6))
```

How do I create a method that goes through this to create an expression that is in normal format? For example, like this:

```
(2 - 3 + 5) * 6
```

Should I be working with the actual expression tree or the String orientation of the expression tree (as shown above as: (*(+(5)(-(2)(3)))(6))).

Answer (score 0):

You should use prefix to infix conversion algorithm.

It's because your expression tree string is in prefix form and you want it in infix form.

You can remove all the braces in input string. That way it will be easier.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I up-voted you but it doesn't show up because I have low reputation. Do you think using a stack for this would be the best way to do it?

Comment: I solved your problem.. that's enough for me. And yeah, stack is the best way to solve such types of problems because of its LIFO property.

Answer (score 0):

About that I advise you to read these documents.

Shunting-yard algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

This algorithm is about 'tokens' stacking according to their "precedence power", per example, a function between parenthesis comes first. As for that read these:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations
>
> http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/ (This one is specific for programming)

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)